# How to exclude Dictionary properties such as Comparer when getting properties using Reflection TypeDescriptor.GetProperties?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the below line of code to get the properties on an object which is validated to a dictionary object at run time.

```
 Dim properties As System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection = _
                          System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(pObject)
```

But it is including Comparer property as well in the properties result. How can I exclude that property? Does anyone know any workaround?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: So you want to get the properties of your derived class, and ignore the properties of the base class?

Comment: Actually, a small change in my question. I will need Keys and Values as well but just the Comparer I need to exclude. Thanks!

Comment: I modified my question now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you know what properties you want to exclude (by name) you can exclude them explicitly. But the `PropertyDescriptorCollection` type is a weird one, as it is `IEnumerable`, but it's not an `IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor>`, and additionally, if you get it via `GetProperties` call it's read-only, so you cannot remove from it directly.
What you can do, is create a new list, move everything you need there, and then, create a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` from your new list, like this:

```
Dim pObject = New Dictionary(of string, string)
Dim properties As PropertyDescriptorCollection = _
               TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(pObject)
' create a new list
Dim propList = new List(of PropertyDescriptor)
' loop through the properties
For Each propertyDesc in properties 
  If propertyDesc.Name <> "Comparer"
    'add those you need to the list
    propList.Add(propertyDesc)
  End If    
Next
'make a new collection with the properties you need
properties = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propList.ToArray)
```